# Where is the SO query language described?

Tags: support, search

I am looking for a description of the query language used by SO. Yes, I have Googled and searched SO but I obviously have missed it.

I want to look for questions related to several topics. This would involve a query that would match any of a few "tags" and any of several words or grep-line words (leading/training * for example) sorted by newest. I want a format that can be used in a web query.

I have some queries that should work and mostly do but not always and that is what I don't understand.

Comment: Possible type: trailing instead of training. (I just stumbled over it for the second time, so I suggest an edit. Can't minor-edit myself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click "advanced search tips" in the right column for details about the functionality of SO's search. Then click through to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for all the gritty details.

[image]

Comment: Not withstanding that I see no "advanced search tips" anywhere I did find the information in the help center, somehow I missed that.

Comment: I think I solved my problem, it seems that an "*" can not be used as the first character of a term. The docs state: "add an asterisk (*) anywhere **in** the word, like encour* or Ex*nge" where **in** includes at the the end but not at the beginning.

Comment: Note: I rarley see the page shown in this answer, I have a bunch to SO tabs open and "Advanced Search Tips" is in none of them probably because I only see search results from a search in a URL. Thanks.