# Incorrect search parameters don't show any notification or warning

Tags: discussion, search

We can see the ["advanced search tips"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270451/2257664) which show many options. But if for any reason the options are mistyped, there is no warning.

See these examples, there is no information that these options are wrong:

- [[search] is:q](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsearch%5D%20is%3Aq) != [[search] is:z](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsearch%5D%20is%3Az) = [[search] is:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsearch%5D%20is%3A) -> the parameters are wrong but we are not informed of this
- [score:0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A0) != [score:O](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3AO) -> it displays all the questions and answers but show no error
- [[bug] body:"please"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+body%3A%22please%22) != [[bug] bpdy:"please"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+body%3A%22please%22) -> there is no result, but there is still no warning

Comment: And you searched `score:unicorn` because...?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom : you're right, that's a huge mistype. I'm going to edit my question to show some more realistic errors.

Comment: And what if somebody wants to search for the literal text `bpdy:"please"` ? (I'm being facetious, I don't think a warning would be any more annoying than Google's "Showing results for **body**:please" and "Search instead for bpdy:please")

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : I don't know how to escape a `"` in the search box. See [body:"bpdy:"please""](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22bpdy%3A%22please%22%22).