# Where can I find the list of supported filters?

Tags: support, filtering

This must be a duplicate (so appologies in advance), but I haven't found anything on meta and in the help center, so let me ask: where can I find the list of all filters supported in the search box? All those "by user", "by tag", "by score", "by date"? etc. Even the [tag description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/filtering/info) on meta is empty...

Comment: See [How do I search?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) in Help Center.

Comment: If you mean the search box at the right top [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270450/where-is-the-so-query-language-described) might help.

Comment: Right, thanks, these comments answer my question. My problem was I was trying to search for the "filter"/"filtering" term while this is called "search options"

Comment: @YakovL I have created a tag wiki and excerpt for filtering

Comment: @rene right, thanks! I guess, linking the http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching page there is worthy, too